# Maximize font sized within cell borders in excell

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts

Is there any shortcut or button to maximize multiple cell's font sizes within their cell borders on excel?
I have an excel file which has the same cell size for all cells on the sheet and each cell has texts with different lengths. I don't want to change cell sizes, but I want to change font sizes of each text on cells to their maximum value based on their length.
I have wrapped the texts and I can do this by changing font size of each cell one by one to see if the text goes outside of the cell borders or not, but that's time-consuming.
Is there any shortcut to do that at once on excel?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are trying to maximize (and mitigate), i.e., vertical (cut-off) or lateral (line wrap)?  Also, just some FYI's you may or may not find helpful: you can likely squeeze out a bit more efficacy by minimizing cell padding, and (if in the case of lateral space) using a condensed font, which some popular font families will include a variant of.

Comment: @Arctiic Actually I'm trying to do both. I'm trying to fit the full content within a "fixed" cell's borders using all the space vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells in question, then in the format cells dialog box, on the Alignment tab, select "Shrink to fit" and click OK. Any cells with content too wide to fit will shrink the visible text so it fits in the cell. The formatted font size does not in fact change, so as you change the cell content you do not need to do anything.

"Shrink to fit" is not compatible with "wrap text" as far as I know, as that will expand the row height to accomodate the extra lines, at which point there is nothing to shrink.

Comment: "Shrink to fit" option fits the text within the cell's width, but it won't use the cell's height's extra space to make the text bigger for reading purposes. "wrap text" option uses the height as well, but it cuts-off the text where the height is not enough to display the full content. I need some option to display it fully and use both horizontal and vertical space within a fixed cell's borders. The way changing text size manually does.

Answer (score 0):

Set the *Shrink to fit* option and run the code:

```
Sub fit()
    Rows("1:1048576").EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: It just changes the cell's fixed width and height, which as mentioned, is not appropriate: "I don't want to change cell sizes, but I want to change font sizes of each text on cells to their maximum value based on their length." I need some option to display it fully and use both horizontal and vertical space within a fixed cell's borders. The way changing text size manually does.